# How to parse a string to a list?

Tags: vimscript, parsing

Is there a way in Vim to do the following:

```
let S = '[''123'', ''456'', ''789'']'
let L = parseStringToList(S)
" L is a list containing the string '123', '456', and '789'
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. After the `let S...` line, you have a list that contains only Strings. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, after the `let S`, it's a string containing a textual representation of a list, not a list.

Comment: ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with eval:

```
let S = '[''123'', ''456'', ''789'']'
let L = eval(S)
```

Generally, using `eval` is something you should be wary of. Don't run it on untrusted data. But this does solve your problem.

It's possible there's a completely different approach you should be using, but without context, it's hard to say.